# Почему не выполняется INSERT INTO запрос в SQLite на php?

Tags: sqlite, php

Написал страницу с формой ввода, по нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так ?
    <?php

```
if ($_POST)
{
     $db = sqlite_open("mybase1.db");       
     $today = date('Y-m-d');

     $namePr = $_POST["nameProject"];
     $commentPr = $_POST["comment"];
     // поля в базе :  name, comment - TEXT; autor - INTEGER;   dtb - DATE
     $query_insert = sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO projects (name, comment, autor, dtb) 
     VALUES ('".$namePr."', '".$commentPr."', ".$iduser.", '".$today."')");

     if (!$query_insert) {echo "всё плохо";}
     else
     {
          header("Location:index.php");
     }

}

?>
    <Html>
    <BODY>
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label>Название  <small class="text-danger">*</small></label>
        <input class="form-control" name="nameProject">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Описание</label>
        <textarea class="form-control"  rows="3" name="comment" > </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="text-danger"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>

    </form>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

в  `<form role="form">` - нада указать что передаете методом post